# I want map an array of objects into an object of objects in js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, mapping

I have this array of users.

```
users = [
 {id:"1", name:"Akash", email: "xyz@gmail.com"},
 {id:"2", name:"Akshay", email: "xyz2@gmail.com"}
]
```

I want to transform this array into an object like this.

```
users = {
 "1" : {id:"1", name:"Akash", email: "xyz@gmail.com"},
 "2" : {id:"2", name:"Akshay", email: "xyz2@gmail.com"}
}
```

I am using node js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array​.prototype​.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let users = [
 {id:"1", name:"Akash", email: "xyz@gmail.com"},
 {id:"2", name:"Akshay", email: "xyz2@gmail.com"}
]

let result=users.reduce((o,a)=>{

o[`${a.id}`]=a
return o;

},{})

console.log(result)

// or if you are looking to convert your array into object


let data=Object.assign({}, users);
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array.reduce

```
users.reduce((obj, item) => {
 obj[item.id] = item
 return obj
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code:

```
let users = [
 {id:"1", name:"Akash", email: "xyz@gmail.com"},
 {id:"2", name:"Akshay", email: "xyz2@gmail.com"}
].map(d => {
  return {[d.id]:d};}).reduce((a,b) => {return {...a,...b};});
console.log(users);
```